# Global Aggregation in Flink over streaming data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am currently writing an aggregation use case using Flink 1.0, as part of the use case I need to get count of api's that were logged in last 10 mins.

This I can easily do using keyBy("api") and then apply window of 10 min and doe sum(count) operation.

But the problem is my data might come out of order so I need some way to get the count of api's across the 10 min window..

For example : If the same api log comes in 2 different windows, I should get a global count i.e 2 for it and not two separate records diaplaying count as 1 each for each window.

I also don't want incremental counts i.e each record with same key is displayed many times with count equal to the incremental value..

I want the record to be displayed once with a global count, something like updateStateByKey() in Spark.

Can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Flink's [event-time feature](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/concepts/concepts.html#time) which produces consistent results for out-of-order streams. Event-time means that Flink will process data depending on timestamps that are part of the events and not depending on the machines wall-clock time.

If you you event-time (with appropriate watermarks). Flink will use automatically handle events that arrive out-of-order.

Comment: Thanks!! I am already using event time processing with watermark and its working properly and giving expected output, but the issue with it is I see the output very late, after around 10 mins+ (since my window of events is 10  mins) which is what I don't want.  I want the output to be emitted immediately and then as processing proceeds update the results. can it be done?

Comment: In event time windows are evaluated when the watermark passes the window interval, i.e., in your case when the watermark indicates that 10 mins have passed. If you emit the result of a window before that, your result may be only partial because more data for that window may arrive. You can emit early results from windows in Flink if you implement a custom trigger. This [blog post](https://www.mapr.com/blog/essential-guide-streaming-first-processing-apache-flink) shows how to emit early results from a window.

Comment: I guess writing a custom trigger will solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also one more Issue with eventTime window is that the last few records are lost because job cannot be cleanly stopped. Since flink job is cancelled it loses last window records.

Comment: The problem with the last window can be solved by sending a watermark with `Long.MAX_VALUE` at the end. This will trigger the computation of the last window.

Comment: The Long.MAX_VALUE approach worked, Thanks for all the help :)